# how to convert array to object of same key

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple thing I need to do, which is take an array/list of strings like

```
const arr = ['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png', 'd.png', ...];
```

and map it to an object with the same key "path" which looks like

```
{path: 'a.png', path: 'b.png', ...}
```

How do I do this?

I've tried `Object.assign` to change the array to an object, which works, but then I can't figure out how to change all the keys to the same value. It is a long array so I don't want to do this manually. How do I assign all the keys in the object to "path"?

Comment: one object can't have multiple keys with same name

Comment: Also: why do you think you need (to do) this? That array is already perfectly fine for whatever you need to do.

Comment: If objects allowed you to have multiple elements with the same key, how would you access them? `object.path` can only return one of them.

Comment: what you can do is this `const result = arr.map(x => ({ path:x }))` but that will get you an array of objects like this `[{path: "a.png"}, {path: "b.png"}, {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have repeated keys in one object, instead you can create an array of objects to store all the paths there

```js
const arr = ['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png'];

const arrObj = arr.reduce((acc, prev) => {
  return [
    ...acc,
    {
      path: prev
    }
  ]
}, []);

console.log(arrObj);
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use a reduce, in this way, I hope this solution will be of great help to you

`const object = array.reduce((acc, item) => { acc[path] = item return acc }, {})`

Comment: this code has syntax errors and path not defined

Comment: if that's what you wanted then you should not post this as an answer, but rather make a comment. Well deserved downvote

Comment: You're writing code that needs to be processed by a computer.  The computer won't give you a "pass" because it likes you.  It will just tell you things like "path is not defined" and "unexpected keyword".  Put the minimal effort in to at least run your code in the console before posting it as an answer and you won't get called on basic things.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).